# SVM Classification using R - Variable Length Differ Error

Tags: r, data-mining, svm

I am currently working in SVM Classification problem with help of packages available in R.

Example code given in this website work fine. 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Classification/SVM

But when trying the same program with different data set I get variable lengths differ error. Here is my code.

```
library(MASS)
library(e1071)
data <- ChickWeight
data <- data[-3]  # removing unwanted column  
tune.svm(data$Diet~., data = data , gamma = 10^(-6:-1) , cost=10^(-1:1))
```

Error.

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula, data) : 
 variable lengths differ (found for 'weight')
```

I tried googling about the error but I could find the proper fix or why this error is getting produced.

Please let know what is going wrong.

Comment: You need to set up your formula correctly, by referring to the column without the dataframe, like this: `tune.svm(Diet~., data = data)`

Comment: But why it not considering column with the dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

Your formula should include the columns only, without the data frame (and the `$` operator).  Try this:

```
library(MASS)
library(e1071)
tune.svm(Diet~., data = ChickWeight[-3] , gamma = 10^(-6:-1) , cost=10^(-1:1))
```

The results:

Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:

```
- sampling method: 10-fold cross validation 

- best parameters:
 gamma cost
   0.1   10

- best performance: 0.5641561
```

Comment: Thank you works fine. But please tell me why it not considering column with the dataframe.

Comment: Because that's how the formula works in R.  It saves on typing, and the formula is evaluated in the context of the data frame. You can read the (somewhat terse) help in `?formula`

Answer (score 0):

You probably removed the:

```
'Diet'(target)
```

column before passing it to svm.